# Parallel list to annotate phrases

Tags: python, list

Assuming I have some text ex:

```
text = 'Ophelia is a character in William Shakespeare's drama Hamlet. She is a young noblewoman of Denmark, the daughter of Polonius, sister of Laertes, and potential wife of Prince Hamlet.'
```

and a parallel list of False values

```
wantedWords = [False]*len(text.split())
```

and a list of phrases and words ex:

```
phrases = ['Ophelia', 'Hamlet', 'daughter of Polonius', 'Prince Hamlet']
```

I would like that for every instance of the phrase array that is found in the text, wantedWords is set to True.

Therefore wantedWords list becomes:

```
wanted Words = [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True]
```

Comment: if you consider multiple words in your list `phrases` , length of `wantedWords` and `phrases` won't match.

Comment: why not if they are part of the text?

Comment: for text `'a b c'` and phrases `['b c']`, what do you want wantedWords to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help.

```
text = "Ophelia is a character in William Shakespeare's drama Hamlet. She is a young noblewoman of Denmark, the daughter of Polonius, sister of Laertes, and potential wife of Prince Hamlet."
wantedWords = []
phrases = ['Ophelia', 'Hamlet', 'daughter of Polonius', 'Prince Hamlet']

for i in sorted(phrases, key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True):    #Sorting the phrases list by len of elements. 
    if i in text:
        text = text.replace(i, "*"*len(i.split()))     #Replaceing found phase with *

for i in text.split():
    if "*" in i:
        for k in range(i.count("*")):
            wantedWords.append(True)
    else:
        wantedWords.append(False)

print(wantedWords)
```